# Whom and how to include referees in the CV?

Tags: application, cv, faculty-application

Many job offers state that they the applicant should *include the full contact information for three referees* in the CV. I was wondering about two things:

1) How to decide upon the inclusion of scholars? Naming your supervisor of the PhD thesis might be obvious, but then? Do only professors count or should the referees come from different institutions, etc.? Especially as an ERC (Eraly career researcher), I don't have many senior co-authors or collaboration partners at other universities.

2) Do you ask these people whether it is okay to name them in the CV and they might be prepared to get contacted or should I avoid this?

Are there any recommendations or past experiences that people are willing to share?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you applying to jobs in academia or industry?

Comment: Sry for not mentioning it explicitly. I thought the tag 'faculty application' points towards academia. So, yes the question targets job offers in academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to decide upon the inclusion of scholars? Naming your supervisor
>   of the PhD thesis might be obvious, but then? Do only professors count
>   or should the referees come from different institutions, etc.?
>   Especially as an ERC (early career researcher), I don't have many
>   senior co-authors or collaboration partners at other universities.

This would be a good question to ask your PhD supervisor. They will have a good idea of what is the norm in your field. You have to weigh up the pros and cons of getting a reference from someone who knows you and your work well, but is not in a senior position. Often this can be balanced by having at least one of the other references come from someone senior (likely your supervisor or even head of department).

> Do you ask these people whether it is okay to name them in the CV and
>   they might be prepared to get contacted or should I avoid this?

Personally I only list referees in my CV that have explicitly agreed to write me a letter (i.e. I have asked them before even sending any application). Consider how you might feel, as a busy professor, receiving a request to write a reference letter for someone that you didn't even know was applying for jobs. If they are annoyed at the surprise request, this may affect the tone of the letter they write. Overall, it's definitely far more polite to ask them in advance. Furthermore, the majority of jobs (at least in my field) ask the reference letters to be sent with the application, so you have to ask your referees beforehand anyway.

Comment: Interestingly, in some job offers (in social sciences), they just ask for the name of the referees and not for any reference letters (otherwise and totally agree with you, you would have to ask the referees anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

First I wouldn't put the referee contact information into your CV but rather on a separate page. Second, it is very important that you talk to anyone you want to mention as a referee **beforehand**. You should ask them if they are willing to be a referee for you, they have the option to say no and you should respect that. You can also tell them what kind of jobs you apply for and which of your skills you want them to mention.

To find people who could be referees, your PhD supervisor should almost always be a refere. A secondary advisor is also a good choice. Other professors at your current institution that you have worked with or that have seen you in advanced courses work. Coauthors of papers are great if they are sufficiently senior, I would say that means having a permament position. If you did a masters or your undergrad at a different institution a professor there who knows you well is also suitable.